# Display multiple forms with captures data

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

When i am selecting an option from drop down box then display no. of forms with captures data.
That is looking like this.

I own a form with some fields like No. of Applicants, Applicant Name, Telephone, E-mail, etc...

When i want to select No. of Applicants are 2 then display 2 forms with relevant fields and capture the first form data to other forms.

When i want to select No. of Applicants are 4 then display 4 forms with relevant fields and capture the first form data to other forms.

It is depending upon user selection. But how many numbers are selected by user then display that forms automatically.

I am searching on Google, but not find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using JQuery

let no of applicants 2

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
  $("#appenddiv").append('<input type="text" name="test'+i+'" value="" />')
}
```